# Google maps Geo code error 1004 in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, api, maps, direction

I am getting error code 1004 could not connect to the server error while trying to use `maps.googleapis.com` url.

I am passing address and sensor parameters.

I am using [Google map app url](Https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/Jon?Address=adres&sensor=false) to get directions api in iOS app.I am not sure why I keep on getting couldn't connect to server error.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I am  Getting results after hitting url on browser.

Comment: Can you post the code you're attempting?